# Custom Validator for certain field length and other criteria

Tags: asp.net, validation

I have a text box that has the rule that text length should not be less than 8 characters plus it should have one numeric character at least. I have one custom validation control to display the error message if the above criteria is not met.

Please let me know how this can be done.

Thanks,

Comment: please share what you have tried...

Comment: @tim-schmelter: i suspect its a password text...he wants the minimum length to be 8 not max

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the below one

```
function test()
      {
       var str = $('#txtTest').val();
       var isValid = false;
       var cnt = 0;
       if(str.length >= 8)
       {
         for(var i=0; i < str.length; i++) 
         {
           if (isNumber(str.charAt(i)) == true)
           {
             cnt = cnt + 1;
           }
         }
       }
       if (cnt > 0)
       {
        isValid = true;
       }
       return isValid;
      }
      function isNumber(n) 
      {
        return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using the Password Strength extender (assuming you need this for a password field but even otherwise this idea can be used). Check the demo [here](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/PasswordStrength/PasswordStrength.aspx).

If you want to write a custom validator, get the value in the textbox; then check the size of the text and validate if it has a digit in it. *Remember to write a server side validation method as well.*

You can also use a **regex** to determine the validity of the text entered - check [this](http://www.zorched.net/2009/05/08/password-strength-validation-with-regular-expressions/) article to understand how.

These should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

```
function varFunction()
{
   var myLength = $("#myTextbox").val().length;
   if(myLength > 8)
   {
      alert('more than 8 characters');
   }
}
```

code for length not more than 8 characters

Comment: this is not correct...length should not be less than 8 and there needs to be atleast 1 digit in it.

Answer (score 0):

On Custom Validator, you need to use regular expression to fullfill your requirement.

Regex should be:-

```
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).{8,}
```